# The algorithm used by PHP shuffle function

Tags: php

What is the algorithm used by php shuffle function or where can i get its code. I have to implement it in C language. I have implemented fisher yates algo in C but not good results as showed by php shuffle function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What exactly constitutes "not good results"?

The Fisher-Yates shuffle will produce all permutations with equal probability, *but only if you generate your random numbers correctly*. There's three issues to be aware of here. First, you need a good pseudorandom number generator. The C standard library `rand` usually is *not* a good PRNG (though it depends on your C library implementation). If you're on a POSIX platform, consider using `lrand48` instead. Your system may have other RNGs. If you don't have anything on your platform, a pretty good RNG in very little code is G. Marsaglias KISS generator - you can find the code [here](http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.jones/GoodPracticeRNG.pdf). Second, if you still decide to use `rand`, be aware that it will generate random numbers between 0 and `RAND_MAX`. For lots of implementations, `RAND_MAX` is only 32767, so the usual `rand() % count` will have a very obvious and bad bias if `count` is larger than 32768. Third, `rand() % count` (or `lrand48() % count` or anything similar) is actually a bad idea too, because it too introduces a bias. If `count` isn't a power of 2, some numbers will have a higher probability than others. Also, in a lot of generators, the low-order bits are a lot less random than the high-order bits. You can try to work around this by using `(long long) rand() * count / RAND_MAX` or something similar, but really you're better of using a good RNG instead.

The proper way to generate unbiased random numbers between 0 (inclusive) and `k` (exclusive) is this: First, get a proper PRNG that gives you a large-enough random number (say 32 random bits). Then reduce to the next power of 2 larger than `k`. Finally, if the value is greater than or equal to `k`, try again. This is a completely unbiased method, and will give results that are as good as your PRNG can make them. The code looks something like this:

```
static unsigned int random(unsigned int k)
{
  // You can get rid of this loop using bit tricks, but I keep it for clarity     
  unsigned int n, nextpow2 = 1;
  while (nextpow2 < k) 
    nextpow2 *= 2;

  do {
    n = random32() & (nextpow2 - 1); // random32 is your 32-bit RNG
  } while (n >= k);

  return n;
}
```